# powershell invoke-webRequst - не могу добавить несколько значений в куки

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookie, powershell

При просмотре devtools в Chrome, я вижу куки вида

> ASP.NET_SessionId=pkoz40ollmfsh443qucvup2v;
> .AspNet.ApplicationCookie=chunks:2;
> CookieData1=7AXAO75yKPCBHA7CHp8AZAHFM2CMKoEATA7s;
> .AspNet.ApplicationCookieC1=ewha8Ccy..."

Видно, что куки представляет несколько пар вида ключ-значение

формирую команды:

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$c1 = New-Object System.Net.Cookie('.AspNet.ApplicationCookieC1','blabla'),'/', ($domain))
$c2 = New-Object System.Net.Cookie('CookieData1','blabla','/', ($domain))
$session.Cookies.Add($c1);
$session.Cookies.Add($c2);

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($Url) -Body ($Payload) -Method $Method -Headers $headers -WebSession $session  -UserAgent $userAgent -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

Выполняю запрос к локальному nodeJs приложению, просматриваю, что же мне приходит, и  куки отсутствуют вообще. Если же одно из добавлений убрать - оставшаяся куки отображается.

Как мне сформировать параметр cookie вида ключ1=значение1; ключ=значение2 и т.д.?

[подробности запроса при доабавленном одном куки и двух](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OT8j.png)